# Is this Doro Liberto forever stuck with Android 4.4.2?

Tags: installation

My wife made the mistake of buying a Doro phone, under the impression it was 'easier to use'. Actually, it's made updating the OS close to impossible, which is why I'm seeking the help of the experts on here.

As some of you may know, Doro inserts some sort of software layer between the user and Android, which does the equivalent of shouting: "Did you want to phone your Grandson dear?" in order to assist the more senior user.

Unfortunately, Doro no longer supports this model, so if you go System Update/Update, it takes you into a section called Software Management. After several minutes of 'Checking for updates...', it reports a server error.

I've read multiple times the standard way to upgrade Android on a phone, but the Doro software prevents me from doing that. Doro themselves took five days before 'Technical Support' told me that it was an old phone and no longer supported. When I replied that this answer was neither technical nor of any support, I got a very rude reply!

Any ideas as to how I can get round the Doro nonsense and simply install the latest viable version of Android, please?

My wife is very keen to install the NHS Test & Trace app, which requires a more recent OS.

Comment: You are making the mistake to think Android is like Windows or Linux, a multi-purpose OS that can be installed "everywhere". An Android phone is an embedded device with an OS named Android that is adapted by the manufacturers to each on the market individually. Therefore there is no Android you could install. Adapting Android to a phone require a lot of work. The cheaper the phone and the more modifications to Android was made the more unlikely are updates. Also newer Android versions require more RAM than your old system provides. Conclusion the answer is yes this device will stay where it is

Comment: This may answer your question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236538/if-i-buy-the-cheapest-possible-android-smartphone-today-how-long-can-i-keep-it/236543#236543